# Mass correction in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, quantum-electrodynamics

What is the physical meaning of mass correction in Quantum electrodynamics, for example interaction Photon-fermion. in this document i can't understand the meaning of mass correction physically. " James M. Cline, Physics 198-730B: Quantum Field Theory" pages (8 to 13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very roughly: Imagine light propagating through a medium. Experimentally it is known that its effective phase velocity is reduced compared to vacuum due to interaction with the medium. This can be described by regarding the photon in a medium as a massive particle. So we see that an interacting particle can be regarded as a free particle with a modified mass.

Similarly, if a fermion propagates, it interacts with virtual particles, these interactions are represented as loops in Feynman diagrams and can be understood as a change to the mass in the fermion propagator - the fermion becomes an effective particles with modified mass, interactions with virtual particles being already accounted for.

What happens mathematically is that you can consider all possible diagrams which you get if you start adding loops to the free fermion propagator. It turns out that you can sum up the series of all such diagrams and get something which looks again like a fermion propagator but with a modified mass.

edit: I realize now that we have the scalar $\phi^4$ theory, so please think of "scalar field" wherever I wrote "fermion". In the scalar case we have no photons to interact with but the field interacts with itself (so the term self energy is even more accurate).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And i ask again , is this mass correction related by self-energy of photon (or fermion)  at first and second order for example that given as:                                                                  \begin{equation}
D^{\mu\nu}(k) = D_{0}^{\mu\nu}(k) - iD_{0}^{\mu\rho}(k)\Pi_{\rho\sigma}(k)D^{\sigma\nu}(k)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
S(p) = S_{0}(p) - iS_{0}(p)\Sigma(p)S(p)
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, it is actually the analogue of the self-energy for the scalar case. I am just wondering why diagrams like the last one in figure 7 enter the expansion, afaik only irreducible diagrams should enter it, that is, diagrams which can be split in two by cutting through some of the lines.

Comment: You're welcome! And sorry, I meant to write "irreducible diagrams are diagrams which CANNOT be split in two by cutting through some of the lines" in the previous comment.

Comment: If you cannot,  give me the source,  please

Comment: For example http://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/582-chapter11.pdf (bottom of page 14)